# Avoid duplicate coumn entries in KendoUI grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using the following Kendo Grid.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EStoreApp.Models.Entity.AccountGroup>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.AccountGroupCode).Width(140).Title("Account Group Code");
        columns.Bound(p => p.AccountGroupName).Width(140).Title("Account Group Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.ParentGroupName).Width(140).Title("Parent Group Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Remarks).Width(140).Title("Remarks");

        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(170);
    })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add New Account Group"))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("AccountGroupEditor").Window(w => w.Title("Account Group")
    .Width(500)))

    .Pageable()
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })      

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetAllAccountGroups", "AccountGroup").Data("getAdditionalData"))
    .PageSize(20)
    //.Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.AccountGroupId))
        .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "AccountGroup"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "AccountGroup"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("Destroy", "AccountGroup"))
    )
    )
```

I want to check whether the "Account Group Code" is already exists or not when adding new one. How can I do it using Kendo grid?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your server-side code to ensure that you are only getting unique account group codes in your data instead of trying to make your grid filter out the data like that.

Change your `GetAllAccountGroups` action to do the filtering on data retrieval.

```
read.Action("GetAllAccountGroups", "AccountGroup").Data("getAdditionalData")
```